# Move common activity objects into 1 class

Tags: java, android, class, object, android-activity

I am creating an app which have similar feature from page to page.

When the app loads it shows a screen that displays options to the users, each of these options loads a page with things to do. All pages looks completely different. Few of them are exactly the same, for example:

- help
- close

Is there a better way to implement this?

Here's my code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    Button ButtonHelp;
    TextView TextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.LayoutHelp);

        ButtonHelp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LayoutHelp);
        ButtonHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_settings);
        TextView.setText(getString(R.string.txt_view_settings_message));

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

public class Help extends Activity {

    Button HelpClose;
    TextView TextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);

        HelpClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LayoutHelp);
        HelpClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_help);
        TextView.setText(getString(R.string.txt_view_help_message));

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Use Fragment where you can pass different content.

Comment: Using fragments is a better way way to achieve what you are looking for. Have a class where you want to hold the values and pass that object to your other class when needed. Define a fragment your project that will replace other views with its own.

Comment: @mike20132013 any example? i never use fragments

Comment: I'll probable give an example by evening.. but in the meantime, go through the developers.android.com and look for fragments

Answer (score 0):

As you have suggested, for the Activities that are very similar, you can re-use a single Activity class, and abstract out whatever is different.

If the behavior is similar, but not similar enough to use exactly the same class, create a base class with the similar behavior, and subclass it to provide the differences.

Comment: Good answer, just keep in mind that java doesn't support 
multiple inheritance, if the project gets larger.